# VBA Userform: Accessing different Charts depending on Combobox

Tags: vba, excel, charts, userform

I am a beginner with VBA, and only have some experience with MATlab.

At the moment I am trying to use a Userform to display different graphs (on that same userform), depending on the output of a ComboBox. I am basing my chart display on [this tutorial.](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_chart_in_a_userform/) In essence the picture is saved as a GIF and then opened with an Image Control.

I have my charts saved as Chart#_####, for example; Chart1_4301. The sequence of numbers is the same as the options in the ComboBox - I want 1_4301 in the Combobox to set the CurrentChart to Chart1_4301 and then to run through the save GIF and load image control steps

```
Private Sub Open_Graph_But_Click()
'This sub opens a different graph depending on the combobox selection

Set CurrentChart = "Chart" & ComboBox1.Value


CurrentChart.Parent.Width = 900
CurrentChart.Parent.Height = 450

'   Save chart as GIF
Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
CurrentChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"

'   Show the chart
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)

End Subb
```

I don't know if its possible to loop through different names of graphs, and I have tried looking up how its done, but I don't know what this is suppose to be called so its hard for me to find something useful.

What I *have* found has led me to the above setup, but I get a Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch, where  `Set CurrentChart = "Chart" & ComboBox1.Value` is highlighted. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Ok Two ways, one, you should know the Sheet Name, so you can assign a chart name by using sheet name like this: set CurrentChart = Worksheets("SheetName").Shapes("ChartName").Chart Or Worksheets("SheetName").ChartObjects("ChartName").Chart. If you dont know the sheet Name, then you can loop through all the shapes like This (not tested, just a sample): 

    For each sht In worksheets
       For Each cht in sht.ChartObjects
            if cht.Name = "YourChartName" then
                set CurrentChart = cht
                Exit For
            End If
       Next cht 
    Next sht

Comment: @Vikas - I can see what you are suggesting, and I think it would work. But is there no way to write a script which allows VBA to access a graph or anything else, which is partly text and partly variable?
If you needed to access 60 different arrays and they were named Array1, Array2 ect. is there no way to say something like For i = 1 to 60   "Array" i ...some code...  next  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I order to explain it, I have created the following macro. I have four charts in the active sheet, Chart 1, Chart 2, Chart 3, and Chart 4. In cell B23, I am entering the "Chart Name" as Chart 1/2/3 or 4, on the basis of which, my following macro works. Whatever chart I enter, it sets that selected chart as Red background, and rest 3 are formatted as yellow background. I couldn't attach my book coz I couldn't find a way to do it. If you still don't understand how to do it, send me your email and i will upload the workbook.

```
Sub RunMacro()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim co As ChartObject

Dim selectedChart As String

Set sht = ActiveSheet ' it may be your sheet like Worksheets("Sheet1") or Worksheets("Sheet2")

selectedChart = sht.Range("B23").Value ' assign the selected chart from combobox

Dim chrt As Chart

'''option 1: Loop through all the charts


For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
    If co.Name = selectedChart Then
        co.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        co.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End If
Next co

'option 2: select the chart directly and popup the size




Set chrt = sht.ChartObjects(selectedChart).Chart

MsgBox "Selected Chart is " & selectedChart & " and the chart is for " & chrt.ChartTitle.Text

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.
Vikas B